# jQuery UI: Y Mouse coords wrong when dropping a draggable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My goal is to eventually set the following css to the dropped object:

```
position: relative; 
top: topOffset; 
left: leftOffset;
```

But although the leftOffset looks good, the topOffset is not.

Note:  This is while dropping a draggable div into a droppable div.  (jQuery UI)

```
$('.paginationPage').droppable({
    drop:function(event, ui) {
        offset = $(this).offset();
        leftOffset = event.clientX - offset.left;
        topOffset = event.clientY - offset.top;

       console.log("event clientX: " + event.clientX + " offset.left: " + offset.left);
       console.log("event clientY: " + event.clientY + " offset.top: " + offset.top);
       console.log(leftOffset + ',' + topOffset);
    }
});
```

The console.log is showing:

```
event clientX: 684 offset.left: 660
event clientY: 205 offset.top: 954.5166625976562
24,-749.5166625976562
```

Based on where my mouse was when this was triggered, it seems the clientY is not correct.  ???

Comment: It's the vertical browser scroll.  clientY is relative to the viewable area displayed by the browser, not absolute to the top of the document.  :(  I need to determine the pixels scrolled off the top somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution.

```
                    offset = $(this).offset();
                    leftOffset = event.clientX - offset.left;
                    topOffset = event.clientY - offset.top + $(document).scrollTop();
```